# Why is editing one member in a list changing other values

Tags: python

```
def result(board, action):  
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    r_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
    r_action = action
    if r_board[r_action[0]][r_action[1]][r_action[2]][r_action[3]]!= None:
        raise ValueError
    else:
        turn = player(r_board)
        r_board[r_action[0]][r_action[1]][r_action[2]]= turn
    return r_board
```

The output from printing r_board is

`[[[['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]], [[['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]], [[['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]]]`

When I try manually assign a value("X") to board[0][0][0][0] I get a similar result

`[[[['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]], [[['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]], [[['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [['X', None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]]]`
How I initialized board -

```
def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    base = [[None, None, None],
            [None, None, None],
            [None, None, None]]
    goof = [[None, None, None],
            [None, None, None],
            [None, None, None]]
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            goof[i][j] = base.copy()
    return goof
```

Comment: Clearly `board` contains multiple references to the same row instead of independent rows. How are you initailzing it?

Comment: How did you create the initial `board`? Deepcopy only breaks aliases between the copy and original, not inside the copy.

Comment: Please don't add code in comments. Edit your original post and use the available formatting options.

Comment: Well look at `initial_state`.  You're calling `base.copy()`, which only copies the top-level list.  Your sub-lists now have multiple references to them.  So of course you're having problems like this.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, your `initial_state` is just making lots of references to the same value over and over again. If you want them to be independent, you can't initialize by calling `copy` on something that's already a list of lists.

You could change the `base.copy()` to `copy.deepcopy(base)`, and that would work, but the initialization logic is a little strange as written. Maybe a simple set of nested for loops calling `append` would serve you better:

```
def initial_state():
    result = []
    for i in range(3):
        result.append([])
        for j in range(3):
            result[i].append([])
            for k in range(3):
                result[i][j].append([None] * 3)
    return result
```

Comment: How would I go about fixing this